# how to check if the post id has a new comment?

Tags: php

how to check if the post id has a new comment?

this is something goes on my mind

```
if (hasnewcomment(post->id)){
//echo something
}
```

any suggestion or help will do.
using get the total comment
or anything

please help

thankyou

Comment: I think adding the goal of this might be helpful. Immediately [`have_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_comments) comes to mind. Although that may not check for "new" comments.

Comment: Can you expand what you need to achieve for us?  How do you define "new?"

Comment: im trying to give notification to the user, if there is a new comment in his post id, echo something, i have tried the have_comment, but this will notify the user once. ive trying to figureout on how to use get_comment_number so that if the get_comment _number is morethan the value , then echo something.

Comment: @felix So, 'new comment' means a comment they haven't seen yet? Where are you storing the number of comments they have seen?

Comment: @tim i think its in the same page, where does the deafult wordpress comment stored?im using the wordpress default comment, so technically i dont know where does the seen comment stored

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress hook **[comment_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/)** to retrieve recently added comment and to pass comment id to **[get_comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment)** you will get the post id.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 2 );

function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {

  $comment_array = get_comment($comment_ID );  

  $comment_post_id = $comment_array->comment_post_ID; 
}
```

Comment: but how can i check if the post id has a new comment?

Answer (score 0):

As standard if you turn on manual comment moderation in Settings: Discussion the author of a post will be emailed whenever a comment to their post is made.